# ¿Cómo eliminar todos los documentos de una colección de Firestore?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
/
  Documento 1
    Datos
    Colección
      Documento 1.1
        Datos
      Documento 1.2
        Datos
  Documento 2
    Datos
    Colección
      Documento 2.1
        Datos
      Documento 2.2
        Datos
```

Necesito eliminar los documentos que están dentro de la colección de un documento, por ejemplo, eliminar todos los documentos que se encuentran en la colección dentro de Documento 1.

Para esto tengo el siguiente código para obtener todos los documentos dentro de esa colección:

```
obtenerSucursales(restaurante: string) {
  this.db.collection('restaurantes').doc(restaurante).collection('sucursales').ref.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      alert(doc.id);
    });
  });
}
```

Puedo eliminar el documento utilizando `doc.id`, pero el método `delete()` no existe en `querySnapshot`. Por lo que me da un error al querer ejecutarlo.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar estos documentos?

Answer (score 1):

> *Usted dice: `delete()` no existe en `querySnapshot`*

La palabra clave aquí es: `ref`,  `doc.ref.delete()` por eso le dice que no existe.

Si no me equivoco, creo que solo puede eliminar un documento una vez que tenga un [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). Para obtener eso, primero debe ejecutar la consulta, luego recorrerla `QuerySnapshot` y finalmente eliminar cada una de ellas en función de [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) de su `ref`.

Aquí dejo mas o menos un ejemplo de como podría ser:

```
var query = db.collection('restaurantes').where('doc_id','==', su_id);
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
});
```

---

Otra forma que puede probar:

```
let fs = firebase.firestore();
let colleccionRef = fs.collection(<Su coleccion aqui>);

collectionRef.where("doc.id", "==", doc.id)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete().then(() => {
      console.log("Documento eliminado con éxito!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error eliminando documento: ", error);
    });
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error Obteniendo Documentos: ", error);
});
```

Me disculpo si no funciona como debe, no tengo como probarla en este momento.

Mas información:

> - [Borrar datos de Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data).
> - [delete(documentRef)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#delete)